# Should I be paid the original advertised amount as that was substantially more than what's in my contract?

Tags: salary, united-kingdom

I applied to a job on a government scheme made for young people who have struggled to get a job and found this fabulous internship that offered London’s living wage on the government universal credit website.

However now I’m being paid minimum wage for 18-21 which is substantially less. I was never told that it would be different and am now being told it was a ‘glitch’ by HR except why didn’t they warn me if they knew about it.

The problem is it does say minimum wage on my contract. I’m not sure what to do as it’s my first proper job and its a great opportunity for the industry I want to go into but I’m so frustrated because I turned down two higher paying jobs thinking this paid more.

Comment: Who have you spoken with? It's likely that what you agreed on the contract is what matters, but no reason why you can't ask for the original salary.

Comment: I’ve spoken with my HR guidance person and my universal credit advisor and neither seem to want to help. I’m just so upset because I applied for a £10.85/hour job and turns out it’s £6.56 :/

Comment: This is true and tbh I really enjoy the job as well, coworkers are fantastic and it’s perfect experience for my future so at least there’s that. That being said I’m going to contest it since its the government paying my salary not the company so I’ve no sympathy for them 

Comment: "I turned down two higher paying jobs thinking this paid more." Have you reached out to the other offerees and stated as such?

Comment: I having trouble reconciling these two statements: "I was never told that it would be different" and "The problem is it does say minimum wage on my contract". If you were given the contract, and your contract said it was minimum wage, then you were told it would be different. Unless by "told", you literally mean "verbally communicated".

Comment: **Please avoid using comments for extended discussion**. Instead, please use [chat]. On [workplace.se], comments are intended to help improve a post. Please see [What "comments" are not...](http://meta.workplace.stackexchange.com/questions/72/what-comments-are-not) for more details.

Answer (score 82, accepted):

You've done the right things here, in that you've queried the discrepancy with your employer, and asked for help from your advisor. From a legal position, adverts aren't legally binding - when you sign a contract, you are formally agreeing to the terms and conditions in the contract, and if that says "minimum wage" then minimum wage it is. I appreciate this sucks from your point of view, but this does seem like an honest mistake, and people do make mistakes.

While you've accepted this job, there's nothing stopping you seeing if the roles you've turned down are still available, and if they are resigning in a professional manner from your current job to take one of those instead.

Stepping back a bit, there's a good rule of thumb in life: if it seems too good to be true (e.g. a job is paying 60% more than similar jobs in the same location and industry), then it probably is too good to be true and you should be wary of things like that.

Comment: While I agree with all of that, it may be worth it to check in with a union or other legal expert. While ads are not legally binding, there are regulations about them and you can't just advertise things that then are different.

Comment: There's also another very important rule: read carefully what you are signing.  Any discrepancy with the advertised salary should be queried _before_ signing the contract.  By putting your signature on the contract, you are agreeing to what is in the contract.

Comment: As @AleksG says, _always_ read the contract and sort out any discrepancies before signing.

Comment: You also have a great reason to explain why you are stepping down so quick.  You applied for a job with X salary, didn't notice they changed it in the contract, and was suck with X/2 salary.

Comment: @Tom particularly if advertised "on a government scheme". At the very least, any misrepresentation (accidental or not) using public funds is unlikely to be looked on approvingly by the administrators of the scheme.

Comment: This is exactly why... I read every line of every contract, and if it's in discrepancy, I threaten to walk out until it's updated. Because they may not be able to update it, sure, you might miss out on an opportunity, but you also will likely be stuck in a situation you didn't expect if you *do* sign a bad contract...

Comment: @schizoid Ah the good old "oh we put that in every contract but we'd never actually do X". I simply walk out of any interview with a company that puts such a contract in front of me. If they're already negotiating in bad faith in the initial stage, it's exceedingly likely there are other dubious things around as well.

Comment: @Tom The add almost certainly said something like "Up to $blah", "Up to $blah based on experience", or something, and OP just got tunnel visioned into that final number and ignored the important bits. OP seems young, and is probably not experienced, and perhaps didn't think to negotiate this bit before signing the contract.

Comment: Guys, why you're right about reading contracts, don't forget the situation the OP is in. He's not in a position to negotiate contracts. I've got lots and lots of things changed in my last contract as well, but I wasn't applying for a government scheme for people struggling to find a job. So take it easy on the OP. He's unlikely to have much experience and is unlikely to be in a position to say "no" or negotiate.

Comment: @SnakeDoc agree completely. Still it might be worth to have this checked. I remember here in Europe there was a scandal when airlines advertised really cheap flights as "from €19" and it turned out that on every plane there was exactly ONE seat for that price. While technically truthful, it didn't fly with the regulators.